# Nginx get file from cache instead of update it

Tags: nginx, nginx-cache

There is no value for proxy_cache_valid in my nginx.conf file so as default it is equal to 1 hour. But I want for specific file set very small updating period, e.g. 10s, so I added to response a header "cache-control" that is equal to "max-age=60,proxy_cache_valid any 10s"

than I wait for 20 seconds and make second request to get the file, but in access.log I find that upstream_cache_status is equal to HIT instead of UPDATING,

Is it possible to update cached file in time specified in a response header?